# Ubuntu 14.10 + SDCARD not mounted

Tags: 14.04

Upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 and the SD card does not mount anymore.
What is the fix ? In 14.04 the exFAT fuse modules were installed and working. After the upgrade seeing that it can't see my files on SD I have removed the exFAT fuse and re-installed but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug of util-linux (libblkid1) that has already been fixed upstream but not in Ubuntu yet.

Please tag yourself as an affected user to speed up the bugfixing process:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1389021

Comment: Installing the [lastest version of libblkid1 from 15.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/libblkid1) and restarting fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your cardreader kompatible with your SD-Card? If its possible, test your Card/Reader combi at other operating system (maybe Windows?) to see whether the card is mounting.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Two 64GB exfat SD-Cards did not trigger the usual pop-up from the device notifier when inserted into the card reader.

The card reader did work before the upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 with exactly the same cards.

I put one of the cards back into the camera where I originally did use them. It was mounted and all photos where still present.

So, the card still works too.

Then I connected the camera via USB and failed too, with an error message I didn't spend any time at all investigating.

I popped the card back into the card reader and looked at dmesg. It showed that the drive was present and the card found:

```
[185803.737955] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 123860992 512-byte logical blocks: (63.4 GB/59.0 GiB)
[185803.741323]  sdd: sdd1
```

So I tried to mount the card on the terminal/console.
This resulted in following error message:

```
mount: /dev/sdd1: more filesystems detected. This should not happen,
       use -t <type> to explicitly specify the filesystem type or
       use wipefs(8) to clean up the device.
```

OK, I mounted it using -t exfat, and succeeded.

Mounting manually on the terminal/console is a viable workaround, but it is not really pretty and should not happen on a modern OS.

I'm really disappointed with the little nags 14.10 is showing so far. Nothing I wasn't able to overcome, but something I haven't seen in a while on Ubunut/Kubuntu